# Wordpress category filter with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, categories

is there any solution for filtering by post categories with pagination. At present, it only filter the posts are in the current page, but not anymore. You can see here: [The Method Case](http://www.themethodcase.com/category/stories/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WP_Query` for this purpose. For example:

```
<?php

$posts = WP_Query(array(
  'category_name' => 'my-category',
  'paged' => 2 // Page 2
));

while($posts->have_posts()): $posts->the_post();
  // do some stuff
endwhile;

?>
```